# MySQL joining most recent record from another query is slow

Tags: mysql, optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have the two following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `modlogs` (
  `mod` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(39) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `board` varchar(58) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `mod` (`mod`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

CREATE TABLE `mods` (
  `id` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` char(64) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL COMMENT 'SHA256',
  `salt` char(32) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `type` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
  `boards` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`,`username`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=933 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I want to join the most recent log entry with the mod's name, however my query is very slow (takes 5.23 seconds):

```
SELECT *
FROM mods LEFT JOIN
     modlogs
     ON modlogs.mod = mods.id
     AND modlogs.time = (SELECT MAX(time)
                         FROM mods
                         WHERE mods.id = modlogs.mod
                        );
```

All other answers on SO also seem to use dependent subqueries. Is there a way I can do this in a way that will return results more quickly?

Comment: time is not a column in mods? Did you try doing the complete join and then order, group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution, putting the subquery into a *derived table* avoids the problem of a dependent subquery. It'll run the subquery just once.

```
SELECT *
FROM mods AS m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ml1.* 
    FROM modlogs AS ml1 
    JOIN (
        SELECT `mod`, MAX(time) AS time
        FROM modlogs 
        GROUP BY `mod`   
    ) AS ml2 USING (`mod`, time)
) AS ml ON m.id = ml.`mod`;
```

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting "Every derived table must have its own alias" with this (I had to add some backticks as "mod" is a keyword ;) )

Comment: Thank you very much :) I'll have to learn about how to write derived tables, I didn't know you could do this

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mods LEFT JOIN
     modlogs
     ON modlogs.mod = (SELECT MAX(time)
                       FROM modlogs
                       WHERE mods.id = modlogs.mod
                      );
```

This query does not make sense.  You are comparing something called `mod` to a max time.  Sounds like it won't work to me, but then there are some very "clever" data models out there.  I suspect you really want:

```
SELECT *
FROM mods LEFT JOIN
     modlogs
     ON mods.id = modlods.mod and
        modlogs.time = (SELECT MAX(time)
                        FROM mods
                        WHERE mods.id = modlogs.mod
                       );
```

I wouldn't write the query this way, because `join` conditions in the `on` clause seem confusing to me.  But, you did.  You can get better performance with an index.  I would suggest:

```
create index modlogs_mod_time on modlogs(mod, time);
```

I would write the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM mods LEFT JOIN
     modlogs
     ON mods.id = modlods.mod
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM modlogs ml2
                  WHERE modlogs.mod = ml2.mod and
                        ml2.time > modlogs.time
                 );
```

Comment: Your query (even with the index) is no faster than mine. Also, you're right, I made an error in my question. Copied the wrong query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also solve this one with an anti-join, though I'm skeptical of the performance on this one:

```
SELECT mods.*, modlogs.*
FROM mods
LEFT JOIN modlogs
  ON modlogs.mod = mods.id
LEFT JOIN mods m2
  ON m2.id = modlogs.mod
  AND m2.time < modlogs.time
WHERE m2.id IS NULL
```

Ensure you have an index on `modlogs(mod)`, and consider the index `mods(id, time)` for better performance.